# GORM embedded struct not getting migrated to SQL

Tags: sql, go, model, migration, go-gorm

I am declaring the following models in GORM :

```
type DBModel struct {
    ID        uint       `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    CreatedAt *time.Time `json:"_"`
    UpdatedAt *time.Time `json:"_"`
    DeletedAt *time.Time `json:"_"`
    ClientID  uint       `gorm:"not_null"`
}

type Address struct {
    address string
    city    string
    state   string
    pincode int
    country string
}

type Office struct {
    DBModel        DBModel `gorm:"embedded"`
    Address        Address `gorm:"embedded"`
    Name           string
}
```

On running

```
func Init(db *gorm.DB) {
    DB = db
    DB.AutoMigrate(&models.Office{})
}
```

The Office table being migrated has fields:

```
id
created_at
updated_at
deleted_at
client_id
name
```

Why is the Address struct not being embedded ?

Comment: your JSON tag value must be set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay understood it.

The fields of the Address struct should be **exported fields**.
Fields must start with capital letters to be exported.

Changing the Address struct does the work :

```
type Address struct {
    Address string
    City    string
    State   string
    Pincode int
    Country string
}
```